# Undefined method 'each' for Student:Class

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, nomethoderror

I want to load a file, split its content into arrays, and have the class apply to the content.

```
class Student
    def initialize( name, grade )
        @name = name
        @grade = grade
        @grade = @grade.to_i
        @newgrade = @grade*1.45
    end

    def show()
        return "#{@name} ,#{@grade} , #{@newgrade}" 
    end
end

# Opening the file into an array
arr = File.open("exam_results.txt", "r+")
allStudents = Array.new

for a in arr
    b = a.split(",")
    name = b[0]
    score = b[1]
    allStudents << Student.new(@name, @grade)
end

for i in Student
    puts show()
end
```

I'm getting

> undefined method 'each' for Student:Class (NoMethodError)

on line 28, which is the `puts show()` line. Any clues on how I can get further on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo there (among other things). You're doing this:

```
for i in Student
  puts show()
end
```

Clearly, the `Student` class is not a collection which you can iterate. I think, what you meant to write is this:

```
allStudents.each do |student|
  puts student.show
end
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are trying to iterate over "Student" class and not Array/Collection object at `for i in Student`

Basically you are doing it wrong. It rather should be something like

```
allStudents.each do |student|
  puts student.show
end
```